# WordPress function for detecting what page has loaded?

Tags: php, wordpress

is there a wordpress function that I can use to detect pages? example of what I want to do is below.

```
<?php if( is_FUNCTION_page('Contact Us') ) : ?>

...display this <div> / xhtml

<?php else: ?>

something else <div>

<?php endif;?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check [is_page()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page) function:

```
is_page();
// When any single Page is being displayed.

is_page(42);
// When Page 42 (ID) is being displayed.

is_page('Contact');
// When the Page with a post_title of "Contact" is being displayed.

is_page('about-me');
// When the Page with a post_name (slug) of "about-me" is being displayed.

is_page(array(42,'about-me','Contact'));
// Returns true when the Pages displayed is either post ID 42, or post_name "about-me", or post_title "Contact".  Note: the array ability was added at Version 2.5.
```

Answer (score 2):

Yeah. Use Wordpress [is_page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page) function to do that.

Example:

```
<?php if( is_page('Contact Us') ) : ?>

<div> Your If content goes here </div>

<?php else: ?>

<div> something else </div>

<?php endif;?>
```

***NOTE:***

**Cannot Be Used Inside The Loop**

Due to certain global variables being overwritten during The Loop is_page() will not work. In order to use it after The Loop you must call wp_reset_query() after The Loop.